# How to show post views on single.php page?

Tags: views

how to show post views on single.php?
What I tried:

```php
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

It works well and counts the views but it counts views every time even a single viewer refreshes the page again and again. I want to play with session cookies but don't know how to achieve that. What I tried to achieve that is I replaced the second function with the below function:

```php
function setPostViews($postID) {
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
$count = 0;
delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
}else{

/*
* Check the cookie is exist or not.
* If not the set cookie for some time interval and
* increase the count
*/
if(!isset($_COOKIE['wpai_visited_ip']))

$count++;
update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);

// Get IP address
$visit_ip_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Set the cookie
setcookie('wpai_visited_ip', $visit_ip_addr, time()+ (60 * 1));

}
}
```

But it doesn't work, I got the following error:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:287) in C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\wp-content\themes\portfolio\breadcrumb.php on line 152

Please help if anyone can do it for me.
I just need to increase views counter when a new user views my post in a single session.

Comment: Can you post the full version of breadcrumb.php and note which line is 152?

Comment: This is line 152:

setcookie('wpai_visited_ip', $visit_ip_addr, time()+ (60 * 1));

Comment: Great, thanks for confirming that. What triggers the function `setPostViews` - is it set to hook in somewhere? For example: `add_action('init','setPostViews');`

Comment: I am not confirmed about that, I think this line executes the function:


remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);


I used this line to call this function on my single.php:

<?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>

And I added this line in while loop to set post view:
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { setPostViews(get_the_ID()); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of the `getPostViews` function looks fine, and I don't see an issue having that inside your single.php or breadcrumbs.php.

However, I would move both functions into your functions.php ([more info here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/functions-php/)) and rather than calling `setPostViews` inside single/breadcrumbs.php, I would attach it to a WordPress action.

```
<?php
//...inside your functions.php...

add_action( 'init', 'fa_setpostviews' );
function fa_setpostviews() {
    global $post;

    // Do not continue if we do not have a post ID
    if ( ! isset( $post->ID ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Do not continue if the user is not logged in
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Make sure the user is on a single post.
    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        return;
    }

    /*
     * Note! The above if statements could be combined into one.
     */

    $postID = $post->ID;

    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count     = get_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, true );
    if ( $count == '' ) {
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta( $postID, $count_key );
        add_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, '0' );
    } else {
        if ( ! isset( $_COOKIE['wpai_visited_ip'] ) ) {
            $count ++;
        }

        update_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, $count );

        $visit_ip_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        setcookie( 'wpai_visited_ip', $visit_ip_addr, time() + ( 60 * 1 ) );

    }
}
```

The above function checks if the user is logged in, if the user is on a single post page and then executes the count script as before.

**Note:** This is on the `init` hook, which may not be the best hook for your uses. Init is called multiple times and you may want to hook into `wp` instead. See more here on hooks and actions: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: It worked. Really thanks a lot man!.